# Content searching in a web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to do a content search in my database. And the requirement is it has to be like a google search completely based on Ajax. Can you guys suggest me any framework or architecture or any kind of idea?

```
Example: 
Employee Table contains Employee First Name, Last Name , Middle Name and Email. I have to search the table by providing any one of the field and the details of that employee should be populated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an index-based search engine. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is immensely popular, high-performant and well documented.

Comment: +1 - Have a look at SOLR (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It can build an index from your database, allowing you to send google style searches to the search index, leaving your database alone.

Answer (score 1):

There are different parts to your question:
1) Ajax library: you could use Jquery which provides simple ajax methods http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

2) On the server end there are a couple of options depending on the type of database youre using. Is it relational, is it nosql? Is your choice of database flexible or is it set in stone?
Lucene provides a query language for an index with more complex information and search requirements. But if your use case is as simple as the one above, you might just shoot off different SQL queries (assuming your database is relational).

Comment: Yes I am using a relational database. So you are saying that sql queries will work?. But the contents i have are in millions. So shooting of sql queries with a like operation is going to be very costly.

Comment: Oh.. I thought you were just looking for exact matches and not in record matching. In that case lucene might be a good bet. Like will be expensive on millions of records. Lucene will index your content for you.

Comment: @user868459- But then a file store will be created in the server context right?.